# Plupload and uniqid();

Tags: php, mysql, plupload

I am trying to join 2 database tables with php `uniqid()`.

My problem is the following:

When I upload my images using [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/), the upload.php runs, generates a `uniqid()` and uploads the images with this `uniqid()`. On the other hand, when I submit my form, the upload.php runs again, and generates a different `uniqid()` as the first one. So I cannot join the 'property' table with the 'images' table. Could you provide some examples of solving this issue?

Structure of tables:

```
Table: images
id : property_id : file_name : file_size

Table: property
id : property_id : property_name : price
```

Something like this, and I tried property_id to be a uniqid();

Upload.php

```
// Settings
$targetDir = ini_get("upload_tmp_dir") . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "plupload";
$targetDir = 'uploads';
$cleanupTargetDir = true; // Remove old files
$maxFileAge = 5 * 3600; // Temp file age in seconds


// Create target dir
if (!file_exists($targetDir)) {
    @mkdir($targetDir);
}

// Get a file name
if (isset($_REQUEST["name"])) {
    $fileName = $_REQUEST["name"];
} elseif (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $fileName = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
} else {
    $fileName = uniqid("file_");
}

$filePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;

// Chunking might be enabled
$chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
$chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;


// Remove old temp files    
if ($cleanupTargetDir) {
    if (!is_dir($targetDir) || !$dir = opendir($targetDir)) {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 100, "message": "Failed to open temp directory."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }

    while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
        $tmpfilePath = $targetDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;

        // If temp file is current file proceed to the next
        if ($tmpfilePath == "{$filePath}.part") {
            continue;
        }

        // Remove temp file if it is older than the max age and is not the current file
        if (preg_match('/\.part$/', $file) && (filemtime($tmpfilePath) < time() - $maxFileAge)) {
            @unlink($tmpfilePath);
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
}   


// Open temp file
if (!$out = @fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunks ? "ab" : "wb")) {
    die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 102, "message": "Failed to open output stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
}

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])) {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 103, "message": "Failed to move uploaded file."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }

    // Read binary input stream and append it to temp file
    if (!$in = @fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "rb")) {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }
} else {    
    if (!$in = @fopen("php://input", "rb")) {
        die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 101, "message": "Failed to open input stream."}, "id" : "id"}');
    }
}

while ($buff = fread($in, 4096)) {
    fwrite($out, $buff);
}

@fclose($out);
@fclose($in);

// Check if file has been uploaded
if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) {
    // Strip the temp .part suffix off 
    rename("{$filePath}.part", $filePath);
    include 'db.php';

    $flat_id = uniqid();


 $price                 = $_POST['price'];
 $propname          = $_POST['propname'];

// Perform queries 

mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO property (flat_id,property_name,price) 
VALUES ('$flat_id','$propname','$price'')") or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $sql - Error: ".mysqli_error($con), E_USER_ERROR);

 $query="INSERT into images (`flat_id`,`FILE_NAME`) VALUES('$flat_id','$fileName'); ";

    mysqli_query($conn, $query);            
}

// Return Success JSON-RPC response
die('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "result" : null, "id" : "id"}');
```

Comment: never used this particular script but perhaps you can store the id in a session for reuse

Comment: can You give the structure of tables?

Comment: so You want to write SELECT query to get property and related files?

Comment: I am using the following: SELECT file_name from images WHERE property_id = "$row["property_id"]... and this will give me the images. But the problem is that the upload function will not give me the same uniqids..

Comment: understood, plz add the code of upload php script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83695/discussion-between-num8er-and-tibor).